# How to parse a string for specific values using PATINDEX and SUBSTRING?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have the following example:

```
declare @test1 varchar(max) = 'Month 05/2022, Ord195506 Cst373175'
declare @test2 varchar(max) = 'Month 05/2022, Ord195506 Cst373175, something...'

select SUBSTRING(@test, PATINDEX('%Ord[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @test1) + 3, 6)
```

I need to get the following values:

- 05/2022
- 195506
- 373175

It must be noted that the numbers behind `Ord` and `Abo` are not fixed to a length of 6. They can be from 1 to any number.

Is it even possible to split the string into required values without a multitude of `PATINDEX`, `SUBSTRING` and `RIGHT`?

Comment: Honestly, this is not a task for SQL Server; its text parsing abilities are poor at best.

Comment: You need that in columns, right, and not one row per each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example in your question you could *string_split* the elements in the string on the space and then remove the non-numeric elements using *translate*, such as:

```
declare @test1 varchar(max) = 'Month 05/2022, Ord195506 Cst373175'

select result
from (select @test1)t(test)
cross apply(
  select Trim(Translate([value],'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,',Space(27))) result
    from String_Split(test, ' ')
)s
where result !='';
```

[Example DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ee531ab2e503800726afe8565e5c0962)

Comment: Hint: `enable_ordinal` to know which value is what. But is that only supported on Azure?

Comment: *But is that only supported on Azure* - yes, until SQL Server 2022.